how we get $ M_2 / M_1=h(c)+O(1 / \log T) . $
Let
$$
A(t)=\sum_{k \leqslant K} a_k k^{-i t}
$$
and let
$$
M_1=\int_T^{2 T}|A(t)|^2 d t ; \quad M_2(c)=\int_{-\pi c / \log T}^{\pi c / \log T} \sum_{T \leqslant \gamma \leqslant 2 T}|A(\gamma+\alpha)|^2 d \alpha .
$$
The first by term-by-term integration, the second by Cauchy's theorem applied to
$$
\int \frac{\zeta^{\prime}}{\zeta}(s-i \alpha) A\left(-i\left(s-\frac{1}{2}\right)\right) A\left(i\left(s-\frac{1}{2}\right)\right) d s,
$$
where the path of integration is a rectangle with vertices $a+i T, a+2 i T, 1-a+2 i T$, $1-a+i T$ where $a=1+1 / \log T$. Then we find that
$$
M_2 / M_1=h(c)+O(1 / \log T) .
$$
Where
$h(c) = c - \operatorname{Re} \left( 
\frac{\sum_{\substack{n, k \\ n k \leq K}} a_k \bar {a_{n k}} g(n) \Lambda(n) n^{-1/2}}{\sum_{k \leq K} |a_k|^2} 
\right),
$
with
$
g(n) = \frac{2 \sin\left(\pi c \log n / \log T \right)}{\pi \log n}.
$
I trying to solve this ,
My solution is :: Here I am trying to show that $M_2=M_1h(c)+/O(M_1/logT)$
by above integral, pole of this integrand  under Riemann hypothesis is   at Given that $\( s - i\alpha = \frac{1}{2} + i\gamma \)$, we get
$
s - \frac{1}{2} = i(\alpha + \gamma).
$
Hence, by Cauchy's theorem under the given path, the integral is equal to
$
\frac{1}{2\pi i} \sum_{T \leq \gamma \leq 2T} |A(\gamma + \alpha)|^2.
$
now if we integrated both side w.r.t $alpha$  from $-\frac{\pi c}{logT}$ to  $\frac{\pi c}{logT}$  then in right hand side we got M_2, but in left hand  side , how we will get $M_1h(c)+O(\frac{M_1}{logT})$ term?
Anyone help me please . if anyone solve this in another way please solve ,.  Thank you
